# Data Validity Update

Tags: data

My question is simple. I want to run Orange to predict where will road accidents take place on a highway. So, I will:

1. Upload the dataset from excel with a few columns and rows of information to be modeled.
2. I will train the information and then run the model based on the complete set of data,say, using random forest and maybe neural networks.
3. I will check the results under PREDICTIONS and will deliver them to an interested party.

QUESTIONS:

a) How long will these predictions theoretically hold, that is, remain valid?
b) If they are valid for one occasion (one-off), can I update the results by making some changes in the information to be modeled, either big or small?
c) Does the app. contain a procedure to carry out these updates in an organized/orderly manner?
Thank you for any help.